# Minecraft LAN not showing up

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have repeatedly tried to use a LAN world with my sister. we are both on the same WiFi. whenever i start a lan world minecraft tells me it has been hosted on ***** port. my sister then checks on her computer and cannot see my world.

I know this has been asked before, here and elsewhere but i cant find a good answer anywhere.

Comment: We don't allow duplicates, I'm afraid.  If a question has already been asked, an answer not working for you isn't a reason to ask it again.  As questions and answers go, the dupe is actually one of our higher quality ones.  I'd recommend reading all the answers carefully for more information.

Answer (score -4):

Make sure your sister is on the same wifi connection you are on.